# SPOJ ISLHOP java wrong answer

Tags: java

I am trying to solve http://www.spoj.com/problems/ISLHOP/

The solution I have tried works for the sample input/output but fails the judging process for having the wrong answer.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.*;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int group = 0;
        while(in.hasNextLine()) {

            int numberOfIsland = in.nextInt();
            if(numberOfIsland == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            group++;
            in.nextLine();

            ArrayList<Island> isl = new ArrayList<Island>();

            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfIsland; i++){
                String s = in.nextLine();
                String[] inputList = s.split("\\s+");
                Island newIsland = new Island(Integer.parseInt(inputList[0]),Integer.parseInt(inputList[1]),Integer.parseInt(inputList[2]),-1);
                isl.add(newIsland);
            }
            double result = solve(isl);
            System.out.print("Island Group: "+group+" Average ");
            System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", result));
        }
    }

    public static double solve(ArrayList<Island> islands) {
        TreeSet<Island> islandSet = new TreeSet<Island>();
        double time = 0;
        islandSet.add(islands.get(0));
        Island current;

        while(!islandSet.isEmpty()){
            current = islandSet.first();
            current.queued = true;
            islandSet.remove(current);
            Island parent = current.parent;

            if(parent != null)
            {
                if(current.parent.curmax < current.curdis)
                {
                    current.curmax = current.curdis;
                }
                else{
                    current.curmax = current.parent.curmax;
                }
                time += current.num * current.curmax;
            }

            for(int i=0; i< islands.size(); i++)
            {
                Island next = islands.get(i);

                if(!next.queued){
                    double dis = Math.sqrt(
                            Math.pow(current.x-next.x,2)
                                    +Math.pow(current.y-next.y,2));
                    if(islandSet.contains(next))
                    {
                        if(next.curdis > dis){
                            islandSet.remove(next);
                            next.parent = current;
                            next.curdis = dis;
                            islandSet.add(next);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        next.parent = current;
                        next.curdis = dis;
                        islandSet.add(next);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        double total = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < islands.size(); i++)
        {
            total += islands.get(i).num;
        }
        return time/total;
    }


}


class Island implements Comparable<Island>{
    public int x, y, num;
    public Island parent;
    public double curdis, curmax;
    public boolean queued;

    public Island(int x, int y, int num, double dis){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.num = num;
        this.queued = false;
        curdis = 0;
        curmax = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Island o) {

        if(curdis > o.curdis)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        if(curdis == o.curdis)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return -1;
    }

}

class FasterScanner{
    private InputStream mIs;
    private byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    private int curChar;
    private int numChars;

    public FasterScanner() {
        this(System.in);
    }

    public FasterScanner(InputStream is) {
        mIs = is;
    }

    public boolean hasNext(){
        try{
            if( read() < 0 )
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int read() {
        if (numChars == -1)
            throw new InputMismatchException();
        if (curChar >= numChars) {
            curChar = 0;
            try {
                numChars = mIs.read(buf);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new InputMismatchException();
            }
            if (numChars <= 0)
                return -1;
        }
        return buf[curChar++];
    }

    public String nextLine() {
        int c = read();
        while (isSpaceChar(c))
            c = read();
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        do {
            res.appendCodePoint(c);
            c = read();
        } while (!isEndOfLine(c));
        return res.toString();
    }

    public String nextString() {
        int c = read();
        while (isSpaceChar(c))
            c = read();
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        do {
            res.appendCodePoint(c);
            c = read();
        } while (!isSpaceChar(c));
        return res.toString();
    }

    public long nextLong() {
        int c = read();
        while (isSpaceChar(c))
            c = read();
        int sgn = 1;
        if (c == '-') {
            sgn = -1;
            c = read();
        }
        long res = 0;
        do {
            if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                throw new InputMismatchException();
            res *= 10;
            res += c - '0';
            c = read();
        } while (!isSpaceChar(c));
        return res * sgn;
    }

    public int nextInt() {
        int c = read();
        while (isSpaceChar(c))
            c = read();
        int sgn = 1;
        if (c == '-') {
            sgn = -1;
            c = read();
        }
        int res = 0;
        do {
            if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                throw new InputMismatchException();
            res *= 10;
            res += c - '0';
            c = read();
        } while (!isSpaceChar(c));
        return res * sgn;
    }

    public boolean isSpaceChar(int c) {
        return c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\r' || c == '\t' || c == -1;
    }

    public boolean isEndOfLine(int c) {
        return c == '\n' || c == '\r' || c == -1;
    }
}
```

I tried simply implementing it using `Scanner` rather than `FasterScanner` because I couldn't figure out how to write the `hasNext()` for `FasterScanner`.

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code as it works for the given sample input.

Does anyone know of a working solution or what is wrong with this one?